# DAX formula to get latest score

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a dax formula to get the latest score for each student for a given month

Table structure:
Student Name, Date, Score, Session

In a given month, there are multiple scores (one for each session). I just need to get the score for the latest date for any student in that month. It does not matter which session it is. Then I need to show the avg. of this latest score in a graph plotted for each month.

Here is what I tried so far but I don't how to do it with dates instead of session

```
Latest score = 
var curr = LASTNONBLANK(tbl[student_name],[student_name])
return 
LOOKUPVALUE(tbl[score],tbl[session],MAXX(FILTER(ALL(tbl),tbl[student_name]=curr),[session]),tbl[student_name],curr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this dax and then create a visual that sorts by month and student:

```
Latest Score = 
Calculate(
    AVERAGE(tbl['score']),
    tbl['date'] = MAX(tbl['date']
 )
```

This will give you the latest score available, without any filtering on student or month, leaving the door open for your visuals to do that work. So for example, A bar chart with month on the x-axis and student as the legend would give you every student's latest recorded score in that month